# Getting input of fieldset by value with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fieldset

I'd need to check a specific input in a fieldset where the elements are defined only by a different value:

```
      <fieldset class="collapsible">
        <legend onclick="toggleFieldset(this);">Opzioni</legend>
        <div style="">
          <table class="options">
                <td class="card-fields">
                    [...]
                    <label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" id="f_status_" value="5" />Chiuso</label>
                    <label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" id="f_status_" value="6" />Rifiutato</label>
                    [...]
      </fieldset>
```

I've tried in many ways in jQuery by something like :

```
$("#f_status_").each(function(){
   if (this.value == 2) {
      this.trigger("click");
   }
})
```

But no luck. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `$(this).click()`?

Comment: You have two identical `id`s in this HTML, so this is an invalid HTML and will cause problems

Comment: and also why you use the same id's for inputs?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  you don't provide enough detail above for us to offer much assistance

Comment: @McHat It's code generated from a Redmine plugin, so unfortuntately the only way to edit the HTML would be to learn Rails :( . I would like to simulate a click on one element (let's say, the one with id=5), and then to click on an "update" button so to automate the selection of that specific value.

Comment: `this` is DOM reference and it does not have a trigger method

Comment: @FedC You have to change the rails code.

Comment: @FedC I have added an alternate solution. But I will never recommend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same `id` reused for multiple elements. That's crime in HTML. Use classes instead and use `.each()` and for `.trigger()` to work, wrap it inside `$()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".f_status_").each(function() {
    if (this.value == 5) {
      $(this).trigger("click");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" class="f_status_" value="5" /> Chiuso</label>
<label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" class="f_status_" value="6" /> Rifiutato</label>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".f_status_").each(function() {
    if (this.value == 6) {
      $(this).trigger("click");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" class="f_status_" value="5" /> Chiuso</label>
<label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" class="f_status_" value="6" /> Rifiutato</label>
```

---

In case, if you can't change the HTML, which I completely disagree as this is wrong HTML, you may do something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[name="f_status[]"]').each(function() {
    if (this.value == 6) {
      $(this).trigger("click");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" id="f_status_" value="5" /> Chiuso</label>
<label class="floating"><input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" id="f_status_" value="6" /> Rifiutato</label>
```

I'll never recommend this approach anyway.

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain? Will definitely take the feedback. 

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Use @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman's answer.

First of all, you shouldn't use `id`s more than once per document.

As for your JavaScript code: The `value` of an `<input>` is returned as a `String`, not as a `Number`. Also, if you want to use `trigger`, you have to wrap the element in a jQuery collection. See a working example below:

```js
$('.card-fields_input').each(function() {
  if (this.value === '2') {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="collapsible">
  <legend onclick="toggleFieldset(this);">Opzioni</legend>
  <div style="">
    <table class="options">
      <tr>
        <td class="card-fields">
          <label class="floating">
            <input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" class="card-fields_input" value="1" />
            Chiuso
          </label>
          <label class="floating">
            <input type="checkbox" name="f_status[]" class="card-fields_input" value="2" />
            Rifiutato
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Er. I answered the same thing 10 mins ago.

Comment: Indeed, you did. Upvoted your answer because you've been faster. Had the snippet editor open while writing my answer, so I havn't seen you had posted the same answer 5 minutes before I did.

Comment: Someone's downvoting both our answers. I'll upvote yours too.